# Can I debug an WP7 app that targets Mango in a real device?

Tags: debugging, emulation, windows-phone-7

Or is the debugging only available for emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's said](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/news/Mango_Developer_Update) that developer devices running Mango may be made available later but, for the time being, you can only debug Mango projects in the emulator.

Edit - Mango Beta is now available to developers to install on their retail devices. You should get an email within the next couple weeks or so inviting you to this, if you're already a registered developer on AppHub. ([More info](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/06/29/developers-get-goody-basket-full-of-mangos.aspx))